# STM32 Pulse Counter

Tags: stm32, interrupt, dry, gpio, pulse

First of all, hello,

I want to count pulses using Stm32. While counting pulses, the pulse giving device will give pulses with dry contact. If I pull up the GPIO to count pulses, I can receive pulses with dry contact. But this may damage the other device. Because there is a 3.3 V pull up. If I pull down the GPIO, I cannot read the pulse with dry contact. How should I proceed in this situation?

I need correct information to make the product in the best possible way.

Comment: maybe https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ will be more suitable for this question?

Comment: Max current a STM32 GPIO pin can sink is 25mA. The internal pull-up resistor has a value roughly 40-47k, so the current pass through the pin is less than 1mA and perfectly safe. Even you use an external pull-up resistor of 10k, it is still way below 1mA. Read this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/511914) or datasheet for further current limit conditions.